# Calculate mutli-level subtotals for Javascript array

Tags: javascript, json, reduce, subtotal

I have a table of data, held as a javascript array which I need multiple levels of subtotals. I know I can use the reduce method of an array to provide a total but cannot get my head around getting the subtotals interleaved with data.
The only way I can think to get interleaved output is as an object or json literal.

For the example table with 'Name', 'Job Ref', 'Location', 'Week No', 'Date', 'Duration' I would like the sum of duration for 'Week No', 'Name', 'Location', 'Job Ref'.

The output would be something like

> {
> "Week No":"Wk 44",
> "Names":[
> {
> "Name":"Elmer Fudd",
> "Locations":[
> {
> "Location":"Town",
> "Job Refs":[
> {
> "Job Ref":"Buy Ammo",
> "Duration":2
> }
> ],
> "Duration":2
> },
> {
> "Location":"Woods",
> "Job Refs":[
> {
> "Job Ref":"Build Fire",
> "Duration":7.5
> },
> {
> "Job Ref":"Catch Wabbit",
> "Duration":19.75
> },
> {
> "Job Ref":"Cut Wood",
> "Duration":9
> }
> ],
> "Duration":36.25
> }
> ],
> "Duration":38.25
> },
> {
> "Name":"Yosemite Sam",
> "Locations":[
> {
> "Location":"Mine",
> "Job Refs":[
> {
> "Job Ref":"Prospect",
> "Duration":17.00
> }
> ],
> "Duration":17.00
> },
> {
> "Location":"Town",
> "Job Refs":[
> {
> "Job Ref":"Buy Ammo",
> "Duration":2.0
> },
> {
> "Job Ref":"Rob Stagecoach",
> "Duration":12.50
> }
> ],
> "Duration":14.5
> },
> {
> "Location":"Woods",
> "Job Refs":[
> {
> "Job Ref":"Catch Rabbit",
> "Duration":17.0
> }
> ],
> "Duration":17.0
> }
> ],
> "Duration":48.5
> }
> ],
> "Duration":86.75
> }

Code I've got up to date :

- totals for all rows as a data table
- groups by multiple attributes (but not perfect as the groupby are concats of the level values)

What I'm struggling with are getting subtotals interleaving with the grouped data.

```js
'use strict';

// input data is in the form of a 2d array with column headers in [0]
let times = [
  ["Name", "Job Ref", "Location", "Week No", "Date", "Duration"],
  ["Elmer Fudd", "Catch Wabbit", "Woods", "Wk 44", "2020-10-26T00:00:00.000Z", 1],
  ["Elmer Fudd", "Buy Ammo", "Town", "Wk 44", "2020-10-26T00:00:00.000Z", 2],
  ["Elmer Fudd", "Catch Wabbit", "Woods", "Wk 44", "2020-10-26T00:00:00.000Z", 5],
  ["Elmer Fudd", "Build Fire", "Woods", "Wk 44", "2020-10-27T00:00:00.000Z", 7.5],
  ["Elmer Fudd", "Cut Wood", "Woods", "Wk 44", "2020-10-28T00:00:00.000Z", 9],
  ["Elmer Fudd", "Catch Wabbit", "Woods", "Wk 44", "2020-10-29T00:00:00.000Z", 6.25],
  ["Elmer Fudd", "Catch Wabbit", "Woods", "Wk 44", "2020-10-30T00:00:00.000Z", 7.5],
  ["Yosemite Sam", "Buy Ammo", "Town", "Wk 44", "2020-10-26T00:00:00.000Z", 1.0],
  ["Yosemite Sam", "Catch Wabbit", "Woods", "Wk 44", "2020-10-26T00:00:00.000Z", 7.0],
  ["Yosemite Sam", "Rob Stagecoach", "Town", "Wk 44", "2020-10-27T00:00:00.000Z", 12.50],
  ["Yosemite Sam", "Prospect", "Mine", "Wk 44", "2020-10-28T00:00:00.000Z", 9],
  ["Yosemite Sam", "Catch Wabbit", "Woods", "Wk 44", "2020-10-29T00:00:00.000Z", 4.00],
  ["Yosemite Sam", "Prospect", "Mine", "Wk 44", "2020-10-29T00:00:00.000Z", 5.00],
  ["Yosemite Sam", "Buy Ammo", "Town", "Wk 44", "2020-10-30T00:00:00.000Z", 1.00],
  ["Yosemite Sam", "Prospect", "Mine", "Wk 44", "2020-10-30T00:00:00.000Z", 3],
  ["Yosemite Sam", "Catch Wabbit", "Woods", "Wk 44", "2020-10-30T00:00:00.000Z", 6]
];

// split to give headers and data by shifting
let h = times.shift();
// then reduce for total Duration 
let a = times.reduce(function (a, x) { return (a + x[h.indexOf("Duration")]); }, 0);

console.log('Total Duration for input data %d', a);

// map the times to an array of timing objects
let t = times.map((row) => rowToObject(row, h));
//console.log(t);

a = groupBy(t, 'Location');
//console.log(a);

a = groupBy(t, 'Name');
//console.log(a);

// aggregate as an array of objects
a = groupByMultipleKeys(t, ['Name', 'Location', 'Job Ref'])
console.log(a);

function rowToObject(arr, headers) {
  if (arr.length != headers.length) { throw ('Row and Headers are not the same size'); };
  return arr.reduce((rv, x, i) => { rv[headers[i]] = x; return rv; }, {});
}

function groupBy(xs, key) {
  let g = xs.reduce(function (rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
  return g;
}

function groupByMultipleKeys(data, keys) { // `data` is an array of objects, `keys` is the array of keys (or property accessor) to group by
  // reduce runs this anonymous function on each element of `data` (the `item` parameter,
  // returning the `storage` parameter at the end
  return data.reduce((storage, item) => {
    // returns an object containing keys and values of each item
    const groupValues = keys.reduce((values, key) => {
      values[key] = item[key];
      return values;
    }, {});

    // get the first instance of the key by which we're grouping
    const group = Object.values(groupValues).join(' ');

    // set `storage` for this instance of group to the outer scope (if not empty) or initialize it
    storage[group] = storage[group] || [];

    // add this item to its group within `storage`
    if (keys.every((key) => item[key] === groupValues[key])) {
      storage[group].push(item);
    }

    // return the updated storage to the reduce function, which will then loop through the next 
    return storage;
  }, {}); // {} is the initial value of the storage
};
```

Apologies for the terrible formatting !

Comment: Could you please add the code you've already tried. Regardless of if it was working or not. In doubt, please refer to the [ask] section.

Comment: thanks to https://gist.github.com/one89/395a3ffb2df4d0648ec7b0caf6cf5d37 and https://gist.github.com/robmathers/1830ce09695f759bf2c4df15c29dd22d to get me this far